# Avoiding array flattening in Lithium validator

Tags: php, lithium

How can I stop Lithium to flatten input values that are arrays before validation?

The Validator::check method in Lithium calls Set::flatten on the input before processing validators, see here:
[http://li3.me/docs/lithium/util/Validator::check()](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/util/Validator%3a%3acheck%28%29)

```
...
$values = Set::flatten($values);
...
```

The problem with this is that it assumes the values in $values are scalars. However, I am passing arrays to the model (which is a MongoDB document).

So

```
'users' => ['foo','bar']
```

will become

```
'users.0' => 'foo',
'users.1' => 'bar'
```

Which totally breaks validation, because it changes the property names.

I could actually just remove the flatten assignment, but I don't want to mess with the internals of the framework. Also I could convert the array to a JSON string, an object, etc. before validation, and convert it back later, but that just sounds lame :) On the other hand, I assume there should be an easy and nice way to skip flattening somehow.

Comment: If you do a dump of the `$options` parameter to your rule (should be the 3rd param), you should be able to get an un-flattened version of the value. I'm assuming you're writing a custom validation rule?

Comment: I don't see why it would be in $options. I did a dump and it is not there. $options looks something like this:

(
    [events] => create
    [model] => app\models\Foo
    [0] => notEmpty
    [message] => 
    [required] => 1
    [skipEmpty] => 
    [format] => any
    [on] => 
    [last] => 
)

According to the source code, the incoming value, if it is an array, is always flattened :(